# Laplacian of step function

Tags: derivatives, distribution-theory, laplacian

Is the second derivative of the step function equal to zero?

$\partial^2_{\theta}\bigg(\Theta(\theta-\frac{\Pi}{2})-\Theta(\theta-\frac{5 \pi}{4})\bigg)= \:?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What follows is *extremely nonrigurous*. By integration of parts, we can 'define' $\frac{d(\delta x)}{dx}$ -

\begin{align}
\int \delta (x) dx &= x\delta (x) - \int x\frac{d(\delta x)}{dx}dx
\end{align}

As $\delta(x) = 0$ at $x\ne 0$, and $x\delta (x) = 0$ everywhere.

So, we can define $\frac{d(\delta x)}{dx} = \frac{-\delta(x)}{x}$.

Comment: But there are two derivatives in my question

Comment: Also, how did you remove $dx$ in the left-hand side?

Comment: Derivative of step function is the Dirac Delta, so one derivative is okay. It is the 2nd derivative which was problematic, as it involved the derivative of the Dirac Delta. That is the formula I derived.

Comment: @Mari: But $\delta(x)$ is the derivative of $\Theta(x)$, right?